# If $f$ is bounded away from $0$ with high probability, are the functions that are close to $f$ in $L^2$ bounded away from $0$ w.h.p. too?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality

This question is related to [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4601860/if-f-is-bounded-away-from-0-are-the-functions-that-are-close-to-f-in-l2).

We consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$, and let $X$ be an $\mathcal X$-valued random variable where $\mathcal X\subseteq \mathbb R^d $ is compact. We denote by $\rho$ the distribution of $X$ (i.e. $\rho(A) = \mathbb P(X\in A)$ for all $A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$).

Now let $f^*:\mathcal X\to\mathbb R$ be a real-valued, continuous function such that
$$\mathbb P\left(|f^*(X)|\le t\right) \le Ct^\gamma\ \ \text{for all } 0\le t\le1 \label{eqn:1}\tag{1}$$
For some positive constants $C,\gamma \in]0,\infty[$. Condition $\eqref{eqn:1}$ means that $f^*$ takes value in $[-t,t]$ with vanishingly small probability as $t\to 0$, and the decay rate of these probabilitis is described by the exponent $\gamma$.

My question is the following : assuming that there exists a continuous function $\hat f:\mathcal X\to\mathbb R$ such that $\|\hat f - f^*\|_{L^2(\rho)} \le \varepsilon$ for a small $\varepsilon>0$, do there exist positive constants $K,\nu\in]0,\infty[ $ such that
$$\mathbb P\left(|\hat f (X)|\le t \right) \le Kt^\nu \ \ \text{for all } 0\le t\le1\ \ ?\label{eqn:2}\tag{2}$$

Similarly as in my previous question, the reason why I intuitively expect this to hold is that if $\hat f$ spends "too much time" in the small intervals $[-t,t]$, because $f$ does not spend much time there, it would imply that $\hat f$ can not be $\varepsilon$-close to $f^*$. My attempts to make this intuitive argument formal have all failed so far though, so I'm starting to wonder whether $\eqref{eqn:2}$ is actually true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.  As a counterexample, one can take $f^*(X) \equiv 1$ and $\mathbb{P}(\hat f(X) = 0) = \varepsilon$, $\mathbb{P}(\hat f(X) = 1) = 1-\varepsilon$.  Then $\|f^* - \hat f\|_{L^2(p)} = \varepsilon$, but $\mathbb{P}(|\hat f(X)| \le t) = \varepsilon$ for all $t \in [0,1)$, so the bound $\mathbb{P}(|\hat f(X)| \le t) \le K t^{\nu}$ cannot hold for any $K, \nu$.