# Does $f(X)$ being bounded away from $0$ with high probability imply that $\hat f(X)$ is bounded away from $0$ with high probability?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ be a probability space, and let $X$ be an $\mathcal X$-valued random variable where $\mathcal X\subseteq \mathbb R^d $ is compact. We denote by $\rho$ the distribution of $X$ (i.e. $\rho(A) = \mathbb P(X\in A)$ for all $A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$).

Now let $f:\mathcal X\to\mathbb R$ be a real-valued, continuous function such that
$$\mathbb P\left(|f(X)|\le t\right) \le Ct^\gamma\ \ \text{for all } 0\le t\le1 \label{eqn:1}\tag{1}$$
For some positive constants $C,\gamma \in]0,\infty[$. Condition $\eqref{eqn:1}$ means that $f$ takes value in $[-t,t]$ with vanishingly small probability as $t\to 0$, and the decay rate of these probabilitis is described by the exponent $\gamma$. (Or equivalently, $f$ stays away from $[-t,t]$ with increasing probability as $t$ decreases)

My question is the following : assuming that there exists a continuous function $\hat f:\mathcal X\to\mathbb R$ such that $\|\hat f - f\|_{L^2(\rho)} \le \varepsilon$ for a small $\varepsilon>0$, is it possible to obtain a non-vacuous lower bound of the form
$$\mathbb P\left(|\hat f (X)|> t \right) \ge 1-\alpha(t) \ \ \text{for all } 0\le t\le1\ \ \label{eqn:2}\tag{2}$$
Where $\alpha\equiv \alpha(t,\varepsilon,\gamma,C)$ ?

Note that I just asked [a very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4683575/if-f-is-bounded-away-from-0-with-high-probability-are-the-functions-that-ar), in which I asked for $\alpha$ to be of the form $\alpha(t) = Kt^\nu $. As [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4683626/857384) shows, this is way too strict of a requirement.

I will be grateful for any help.